# Ionic modal - document.getElementById not working in modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic modal presented like so:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/my-modal.html', {
  scope: $scope,
  animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function(modal) {
  $scope.modal = modal
  $scope.modal.show()
})
```

The modal looks like this:

```
<ion-modal-view ng-controller="EditCtrl" class="modal">
  <ion-header-bar class="modal-header-bar">
    <button class="button button-clear">Cancel</button>
    <h1 class="title">Edit</h1>
    <button class="button button-clear">Save</button>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <div id="foo"></div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

Then in `edit_controller.js`:

`document.getElementById('foo')`

Returns null. How can I have `document` refer to the currently shown modal?

Comment: There is only ever one document that is used for the entire app. Can you put your code in a codepen? With more details, we might be able to help you.

Comment: If you need to access DOM elements of the modal you could do that in a `$scope.$on('modal.shown', function(event, modal) { ... });` handler